# onClick function call not working - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: dojo, onclick

Here is my html in my javasript File 1:

```
<a id='theId' title='theTitle' href='#' onClick='XXXX';>"+theTitle+"</a>
```

File 2 contains my widget where the above html is called and will be created from.

Where I have the XXXX in the html, I need to call a function in the widget file, formatTitle(aVar1,aVar2), that needs 2 string args passed in. I have tried numerous options, but keep getting different errors depending on the syntax I use:

When I try this code:

```
onClick='this.formatTitle(\"aVar1\",\"aVar2\");'
```

I get this error: TypeError: this.formatTitle is not a function

When I try this code:

```
onClick='function xyz(aVar1, aVar2) {this.formatTitle(aVar1, aVar2);};'
```

nothing happens when I click.

Would someone be able to help me out?

Comment: You need to show us how you declare the formatTitle function, possibly it's not in the global scope. One thing that is for sure: this refers to the <a> DOM object on which the onClick is added, so formatTitle() isn't known there.

Answer (score 0):

try to call like this:

```
<a id='theId' title='theTitle' href='#' onClick='XXXX();'>"+theTitle+"</a>
```

Hope it will work.Thanks

Comment: I did try that and it didnt work. What about the args I need to pass in?